# Error al consultar API con python 2

Tags: api, python-2.x

estoy armando un request para consultar una API, pero como el servidor es viejo lo debo hacer en python 2.6.6

Este es el codigo del request:

```
def GetProfile(msisdn,msisdn_type,_token):
fecha=datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
_trace_id=GetTraceId()
_msisdn=str(msisdn)
_msisdn_type=str(msisdn_type)
_headers={
    'x-ibm-client-id':client_id,
    'trace_id':_trace_id,
    'Authorization':'Bearer '+_token
}
_query={
    "msisdn":_msisdn,
    "msisdn_type":_msisdn_type,
    "date_time":fecha
}

query_url=urllib.urlencode(_query)
con = httplib.HTTPSConnection(url)
con.request("GET","<mi_endpoint>?"+query_url,_headers)
resp=con.getresponse()
data=resp.read()
if resp.status==200:
    print data
else:
    print "Error:"+str(resp.status)
    print data
```

Pero me da el siguiente error:
TypeError: unhashable type

No se si es porque esta esperando un body, pero la verdad es que no se que puede estar faltando. Probe agregarle el body vacio pero me dar error 400, lo cual esta bien porque no espera un body.
El resquest lo probe en post man y funciona perfecto.
Alguna idea?

Comment: Mirando el código, no parece haber nada que sepa que es que pueda causar dicho error. Tal vez ayudaría a saber que está pasando que [hagas de tu ejemplo completo y verificable](/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: ya encontre el error, ese request esta esperando el body y yo no lo puse, como va vacio, solo hace falta poner '' y ya.